# Запрос диапазона дат с инфоблока Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь создать форму с бронированием номеров, всего из 3 штуки.
Вообщем суть такая, что в форме задаются 2 даты, дата заезда и выезда, AJAXом отправляю в обработчик, где идет проверка на занятые номера НО) Тут что-то пошло не так...

Немного подробней, принимаю дату

```
// Получаю пост запрос
    $date_in = $_POST["$uniq"]["prop"]["data_in"];
    $date_out = $_POST["$uniq"]["prop"]["data_out"];

// Получил формат сайта
    $format_ru = CSite::GetDateFormat("SHORT", "ru"); // DD.MM.YYYY

// переведем дату из формата сайта ru
    $conwert_date_in = $DB->FormatDate($date_in, $format_ru);
    $conwert_date_out = $DB->FormatDate($date_out, $format_ru);

// Преобразовал ввиде дат
    $conwert_date_in = (ConvertDateTime($conwert_date_in, "YYYY-MM-DD"));
    $conwert_date_out = (ConvertDateTime($conwert_date_out, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
```

Имеется инфоблок куда записываются забронированные номера, в них добавил свойства с типом дата, назвал DATA_IN и DATA_OUT. Также добавил свойство HOUS (Номер гостиной).

Вообщем данные забронированных номеров имеют примерно такой вид:

| PROPERTY_DATA_IN | PROPERTY_DATA_OUT | HOUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-05 | 2022-08-06 | 1 |
| 2022-08-05 | 2022-08-07 | 2 |

Ну и собственно сам запрос...

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "PROPERTY_DATA_IN", "PROPERTY_DATA_OUT", "PROPERTY_HOUS");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=> 5 , "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y",
    "LOGIC" => "AND",
    array(
        ">=PROPERTY_DATA_IN"=> $conwert_date_in,
        "<=PROPERTY_DATA_OUT"=> $conwert_date_out)
);
```

Массив выводит только в том случае если начало conwert_date_in совпадает с днем въезда...
Т.е
Если ввести даты
2022-08-05  2022-08-12 все ок) Работает

Но если ввести
2022-08-06  2022-08-12 то ничего не работает, такие дела

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если что, то вот типа такого запроса вам пригодится

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "PROPERTY_DATA_IN", "PROPERTY_DATA_OUT", "PROPERTY_HOUS");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=> 5 , "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y",
    array("LOGIC" => "OR",
        array("LOGIC" => "AND", "<=PROPERTY_DATA_IN" => $conwert_date_in, ">PROPERTY_DATA_OUT" => $conwert_date_in),
        array("LOGIC" => "AND", ">PROPERTY_DATA_IN" => $conwert_date_in, "<PROPERTY_DATA_IN" => $conwert_date_out)));
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect);
$i = 0;
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
    $booked[$i] = $ob->GetFields();
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужна проверка на пересечение дат, то фильтр должен быть такой:

```
array(
        ">=PROPERTY_DATA_OUT"=> $conwert_date_in,
        "<=PROPERTY_DATA_IN"=> $conwert_date_out)
```